# Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?

Tags: php, oop, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a complex hierarchy of nested objects, with all of the child objects (stored an array of objects in the parent class) containing a property linking back to their parent: fairly simple and straightforward, with no real problems. If I do a var_dump of any object in the hierarchy, I'll get a recursive reference in the dump, exactly as I'd expect.

```
FIRSTGEN 
   _children array of objects of type SECONDGEN
      SECONDGEN #1
         _parent object of type FIRSTGEN
         _children array of objects of type THIRDGEN
            THIRDGEN #1
               _parent object of type SECONDGEN
            THIRDGEN #2
               _parent object of type SECONDGEN
      SECONDGEN #2
         _parent object of type FIRSTGEN
         _children array of objects of type THIRDGEN
            THIRDGEN #3
               _parent object of type SECONDGEN
```

I've recently added some new elements to that hierarchy, and they don't follow quite the same pattern. They are stored in an array of objects in the top-level parent, but contain a property linking them back, not to their parent, but to a sibling. When I do a var_dump now, I get a "Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?".

```
FIRSTGEN 
   _children_1 array of objects of type SECONDGEN_1
      SECONDGEN_1 #1
         _parent object of type FIRSTGEN
         _children array of objects of type THIRDGEN
            THIRDGEN #1
               _parent object of type SECONDGEN_1
            THIRDGEN #2
               _parent object of type SECONDGEN_1
      SECONDGEN_1 #2
         _parent object of type FIRSTGEN
         _children array of objects of type THIRDGEN
            THIRDGEN #3
               _parent object of type SECONDGEN_1
   _children_2 array of objects of type SECONDGEN_2
      SECONDGEN_2 #1
         _parent object of type SECONDGEN_1
```

Everything else within the code works correctly, with the exception of that var_dump(). I've tried creating a simpler example to demonstrate the problem, so that I could provide an example when asking this question; but haven't been able to replicate it in a short test, only within my more complex code.

I know that the solution is to refactor the relationship so that my _children_2 array of SECONDGEN_2 objects is held in the appropriate SECONDGEN_1 parent, making the parent relationship "correct"... I've already started doing this.
However, I'm intrigued by the error, and wondered if anybody else had encountered it (and how you dealt with it yourself).

Comment: Some code would help, but if I were to guess, I would say you have infinite recursion (because I am a sibling of my sibling)

Comment: I wish I could reproduce with a simple snippet of code that could be posted here, but so far I've not managed to replicate in 40 lines or less (I'm still trying to produce something); and even stripping everything extraneous from my main project (when I can reproduce it) it's still too many 100s of lines to post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a PHP limitation in self-referencing code and trying to display it with `print_r`, `var_dump`, `var_export`, or search through it with `in_array`. Basically there's no way for those functions to know where to stop recursing if an object is referenced cirularly.

According to [this bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30471) the easiest way to [reproduce this](http://www.ideone.com/YCnbk) is:

```
$outText = var_export( $GLOBALS, true );
print_r($outText) ;
```

Other bug reports [mention](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39356) it too, with some more test cases. I'd say that if this is only triggered in `var_dump` you shouldn't worry too much about it. I definitely second Wrikken's suggestion about xdebug if this is for debugging purposes.

Comment: The second bug report that you mention is a simple parent->child->parent recursion, which doesn't cause var_dump() any problems... it simply reports the recursion. It doesn't even cause issues with parent->child->grandchild->parent recursion. I was surprised at the sibling case though... from the successful handling of the more common types of recursion, I'd have expected the sibling relationship to be trapped in the same way.

Comment: if it happens with var_export then in some cases, e.g. generating CSV, it makes impossible to debug existing variables, workaround was offered here http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php , search for keywords - WORKAROUND for error "Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency"

Answer (score 107):

### This also arises if you compare recursive objects using `==` instead of `===`

**If you need to compare actual object instances** always use the strict comparison operator `===` as it only compares if the objects refer to the same instance of the same class.

Short explanation:

If you compare objects using `$object == $objectToCompareWith`, PHP is comparing every attribute and value of the first object with the second. This comparison is recursive over objects which are properties of the objects being compared.

That means that if both objects share an attribute with an object as its value, PHP does the same `==` comparison between those attribute objects. Now as soon as on of those attribute objects is recursive (e.g. a self referencing object) the comparison recurses down too until the maximum nesting level is reached.

As stated in the comments by Josh Stuart and mazatwork, strict comparison can be forced when using array functions like `in_array()` and `array_search()` by setting their respective `$strict` parameter to `true`.

[Richard Lord: "Nesting level too deep – recursive dependency?"](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/php-nesting-level-too-deep-recursive-dependency)

[PHP Manual: "Comparing Objects"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)

Comment: flu - you're my hero of the day. So obvious once you read it... Thanks!

Comment: Nice one! This also applies to `in_array` and comparing an array of objects.

Comment: `array_search()` also has a $strict argument for searching in an array of objects.

Comment: but beware not to use loose comparison when utilizing `array_search` (instead of `in_array`) because that would discard the first element in `integer`- indexed arrays as well. Use `if (array_search($needle, $haystack, true) !== false) {doSmth();}`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes (but seldom, as there are limited valid used for such contrustcs) this happens, and as long as your code works properly, I wouldn't give it much thought that a `var_dump` (a debugging tool, not a production one) cannot cope with it. However, if you still *need* `var_dump` to work, I can heartily recommend running xdebug, in which you can set max-depth the `var_dump` will show, the max-length of a string dump and the maximum amount of children.

Comment: I think this is one of those cases where there's my reason for the sibling relationship (to provide a method to list all SECONDGEN_2 children directly from the FIRSTGEN parent) can be done as easily by attaching SECONDGEN_2 children to their corresponding SECONDGEN_1 object, and for the FIRSTGEN method to loop through the SECONDGEN_1 objects calling a listSECONDGEN_2 method there and merging the lists; so not really a valid use. So I'm reworking it anyway.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing the actual structure of references, but it could always be that in a sufficient sample, there is a path for PHP to hop nodes without encountering the same node before it's maximum nesting level. How many nodes do you have, and is there such a path?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error as you but in an entirely different scenario. I'm posting the answer in case anyone else gets here the same way I did.

**In the case that you're trying a custom sort *(usort)* with an array of objects, here's what I had to do:**

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if($a->num_estimates == $b->num_estimates) return 0;

    return($a->num_estimates < $b->num_estimates) ? -1 : 1;
}
$c = usort(Company::$companies, "cmp");
```

It turned out that `$object->num_estimates` was occasionally returning an object instead of a number. Once I made sure it was always returning a number then the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the magic method [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) to define a custom conversion to a string.  Look through your object and avoid going too deep through recursions when implementing __toString and everything should be fine.  Just never forget and accidentally call var_dump, var_export, print_r etc.

Once the __toString method has been defined the following works nicely:

echo $yourObjectHere;

This is my current solution which works well, but I would still like something to protect me from forgetting not to call var_dump, var_export and print_r.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone.

For me, a solution was to raise `pcre.recursion_limit` in php.ini. It's more of a temporary workaround when you read the other answers, though, as the problem most likely lies inside your own code.